# Problem reading RS485 communication packets with raspberry pi using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, modbus

I'm having trouble reading packets over a serial line, in the modbus protocol. I want to read the temperature from my thermometer that uses RS485 communication, so I used raspberry pi in combination with **waveshare rs485 can hat**.

Here is a code sample.

```
   #!/usr/bin/python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
import time
from prectime import processor_sleep

rsp = 4
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(rsp, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(rsp, 0)
a = float(7.5)
command = [0x02,0x04,0x00,0x05,0x00,0x01,0x21,0xF8]
r = str(0)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, timeout = 0.1)

while len(str(r)) < 31:
    GPIO.output(rsp, 1)
    ser.write(command)
    processor_sleep(a)
    GPIO.output(rsp, 0)
    r = ser.readline()
    print(r,' --- ',a)
    a = a + 0.1
    processor_sleep(1000)

ser.close()
```

My prectime library with the processorsleep () function is here.

```
import time

def processor_sleep(ms):
    _ = time.perf_counter() + ms/1000
    while time.perf_counter() < _:
        pass
```

As soon as I connect the sniffer in parallel to the line I can see that the initiating packet is received and answered by the sensor correctly, however, when I try to read the same answer via python the result is this:

```
b''  ---  7.5
b''  ---  7.6
b''  ---  7.699999999999999
b'\x02\x04\x02\x01S\xbc\x9d'  ---  7.799999999999999
b'\x02\x04\x02\x01S\xbc\x9d'  ---  7.899999999999999
b'\x02\x04\x02\x01S\xbc\x9d'  ---  7.999999999999998
b'\x02\x04\x02\x01S\xbc\x9d'  ---  8.099999999999998
```

and it should look like (from sniffer)

```
b'\x02\x04\x02\x01\x52\xbc\x9d'
```

I don't know what's going on, sometimes it happens that I catch the packet well, but it's rare.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use/know Python, but using `ser.readline()` to retrieve what looks like binary data (rather than a line of ASCII text) is probably incorrect. Also, sleeping after the write and then flipping the GPIO is likely to be problematic because userspace is not synchronized with device I/O. If the transition between transmitting to receiving mode is delayed, you could risk losing input. Switch too early, and transmission is then cut off. Usually RS-485 utilizes HW to perform this mode transition.

Comment: But I don't know how to enable the HW transition between transmission and receiving.

Comment: Your device does not support hardware RX/TX toggle. See my answer.

Comment: Why not try the same using Pymobdus, it may make your output easier to understand and, therefore, to debug

Answer (score 1):

This topic has been already discussed at length.

Just go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56922031/11476836) and follow the rabbit hole of links in my answer. You should be able to solve your problem.

I would go for the *libmodbus* solution (there is a Python wrapper too) but you can also stay with *pymodbus* if you want.

Anyway, what sawdust says in the comments is also very good advice. The easiest would be to invest 10 bucks and buy a transceiver that is able to toggle itself. Yours is not, unfortunately.