# Multi clients modbus to single modbus server

Tags: python, networking, modbus

I have two python scripts which need to get data from the same modbus server.

However they cannot be simultaneously connected to the same modbus server, so I am looking for a "proxy" software.

This proxy will then sequentially transfer the modbus queries to the modbus server.
Solution should run on debian 11 lite.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are dealing with Modbus TCP you can try [modbus-proxy](https://github.com/tiagocoutinho/modbus-proxy):

> Many modbus devices support only one or very few clients. This proxy
> acts as a bridge between the client and the modbus device. It can be
> seen as a layer 7 reverse proxy. This allows multiple clients to
> communicate with the same modbus device.
>
> When multiple clients are connected, cross messages are avoided by
> serializing communication on a first come first served REQ/REP basis.

**EDIT:** According to your comment below:

> *...it is RTU over a linux file descriptor /dev/ttyS1*

That seems to me a not-so-straightforward way of saying that you are dealing with a serial link.

If that's the case I'm afraid you need to go back all the way to the physical layer.

If you have a point-to-point serial connection (no matter the voltage levels you have, they can be TTL 3.3VDC or RS-232) there is no way you can have more than one Modbus client connecting to the same server.

For a serial link to have more than two devices (two or multiple clients sending queries to a Modbus server, for instance) you need a way for the devices to take control of the bus when they communicate and let go of it when they are idle. An [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) multipoint serial link is the most frequent solution to this problem.

If you follow the link you will find many resources and documentation. That might be a bit overwhelming but it is actually very easy: instead of connecting RX to TX as you'd do for a normal serial port you will have two cables for each device (they are called A and B or D+ and D-) that you can put together. And you only need to add a TTL to RS-485 transceiver in between each device and the bus (or RS-232 to RS-485, depending on your devices).

There are a couple of nuances:

- You might need [terminating resistors](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/rs-485-basics-when-termination-is-necessary-and-how-to-do-it-properly), but that should only be the case if your devices are far away (more than several meters) from each other.
- If you go for the [cheapest transceivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NIOLNAG) you might end up being forced to toggle the bus in your software, which is not a good solution. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922031/modbus-error-invalid-message-incomplete-message-received-expected-at-least-2/56923891#56923891) for more details. And better aim for something with [automatic TX enable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082Y19KV9).

The most complete reference on all these topics I know of is Jan Axelson's book [Serial Port Complete](http://janaxelson.com/spc.htm). It's a bit old (the last edition was released in 2007) but still very relevant. And you can find older editions secondhand for next to nothing. If you need to work with serial ports, this book will be a very valuable companion.

Final note: if you are not able or willing to mess with the phy layer, you might, of course, find other solutions that are more palatable. You might, for instance, implement a software forwarder to take queries from your clients and convert them to Modbus RTU to be sent to your server. Pymodbus includes an [example](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/dev/examples/contrib/serial_forwarder.py), but since you did not elaborate much I'm not sure it will be useful for your situation.

Comment: thanks unfortunately it is RTU over a linux file descriptor /dev/ttyS1.
I tried RTU encapsulated on TCP but it did not work with the modbus-proxy software

Comment: Now, that's a whole new beast, but see if my edited answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same challenges before and ended up with Modbus-to-MQTT bridge solution, because each protocol has its limit, Modbus is designed for master-slave poll in nature and MQTT is good for multiple clients/subscribers.

**Modbus + MQTT**, such a combination is just nice and could be very powerful in modern IoT applications. You can try [modpoll](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll), which is a python-based Modbus tool and can run as a Modbus-to-MQTT bridge in your case.